# Chrome "Emulate Touch Events" not working

Tags: google-chrome, mobile, touch, google-chrome-devtools, touch-event

I've enabled the "Emulate Touch Events" option in Chrome's Developer Tools.  I set up a simple test program that alerts when I touch a `<div>`.  The program works fine on my Galaxy Nexus, but when I click on the `<div>` in Chrome, even with the "Emulate Touch Events" option enabled, nothing happens.  Any suggestions?  Am I using this tool correctly?

Here's my code - nothing too fancy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>      
    <style type="text/css">
        #main_div
        {
            position: absolute;
            width: 50px;
            height: 20px;
            background-color: red;
            top: 50%;
            left: 20px;             
        }           
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function init()
        {
            main_div = document.getElementById("main_div");             
            main_div.ontouchstart = function() 
            {                    
                 alert("here");
            }                               
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div>
        <p id="x">hello</p>
        <p id="y"></p>
    </div>
    <div id="main_div">
        hello
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm running version 19.0.1084.56.

Comment: Do you by chance have the page zoomed in/out? Event coordinates (both for the mouse and, consequently, touch ones) in Chrome are known to be off by an amount depending on the zoom and page layout. Consequently, you may be just "missing" the target div vertically.

Comment: I checked my zoom levels - I'm at standard zoom.  I also furiously clicked all around my target in hopes that Chrome is just reading my coordinates incorrectly, but alas, to no avail.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: For some reason, DOM0 events do not work with the touch emulation. You can use the DOM2 `addEventListener("ontouchstart",...)` as a workaround. Meanwhile, https://crbug.com/133915 has been filed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What stumped me was that in addition to having the "Emulate touch events" checkbox checked, you also have to have the master "Enable" checkbox checked to enable overrides. Once both were checked, it worked fine.

[image]

Comment: This enable checkbox has to be quite new. I have used this before and not seen it.

Comment: I think it appeared with Chrome 30.

Comment: I found an updated solution described in my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Touch events work in Chrome version 21 (not sure about previous versions) BUT you have to keep the Developer Tools window open in order for the touch events to occur. If you close the window you will go back to normal mouse events.

Comment: Source? Did you experience this yourself?

Comment: "This feature, like many other overrides, will only work while the DevTools are open."
Source: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#emulate-touch-events

Answer (score 3):

As of Chrome 69, there's no Overrides pane in the settings, nor an Emulator drawer in the console. Instead, you can click the `...` icon in the device view and then select "Add device type".

[image: click "Add device type" to show the device type dropdown]

While in Responsive mode, this will show you a little dropdown with the options "Mobile", "Mobile (no touch)", "Desktop", and "Desktop (no touch)". If you don't see it, expand the width of the device view pane. The default for Responsive mode is Mobile (which means touch events).

[image: select which events to emulate in the device type dropdown]

Note that when you select other pre-set devices, the device type will be set to Mobile and can't be changed. You can also select which device type you'd like to emulate when creating a custom device in Settings.

[image: select device type when adding custom devices]

Answer (score 2):

One important point that I've noticed - Checking "Emulate touch events" does not *disable* mouse events, it only adds a touch as well.

Comment: Do you know of a way to disable the mouse events, while emulating touch events.

Comment: I don't think there's a simple way of doing it in Chrome - only catching them and running a preventBubble, stopPropagation, stopImmediatePropagation on the event... though even that I'm not positive would catch all of them first.

Comment: This is because this is how touch events work. They add extra layers on top of click events. Disabling click events when touch is enabled would mean that the emulation layer would be broken compared to how things would work on actual devices.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share the code you tried?
Here's a sample code that worked with me, both on iPhone and Chrome 19

```
<head>
 <script>
function listen(elem, evnt, func) {
  if (elem.addEventListener)  // W3C DOM5.        
    elem.addEventListener(evnt,func,false);
  else if (elem.attachEvent) { // IE DOM7.         
    var r = elem.attachEvent("on"+evnt, func);
    return r;
  }
}

function attachListeners() {
var touch_div = document.getElementById('touch_me');
listen(touch_div,'touchmove', function(event) {
    touch_div.innerHTML="being touched " + event.targetTouches.length;
    touch_div.style.background =green;
}, false);
listen(touch_div,'touchstart', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    touch_div.innerHTML="touchstart";
    touch_div.style.background ='green';
}, false);
listen(touch_div,'touchend', function(event) {
    touch_div.innerHTML="thanks!";
    touch_div.style.background ='#CCFF66';
}, false);
listen(touch_div,'click', function(event) {
    touch_div.innerHTML="hey - touch, not click!";
    touch_div.style.background ='red';
}, false);
listen(touch_div,'onmouseup', function(event) {
    touch_div.innerHTML="hey - that was a click!";
    touch_div.style.background ='';
}, false);
 }

function run_onload() {
attachListeners();
}   

 </script>

 </head>
 <body onload="run_onload()">
 <div id="touch_me">Touch me!</div>
 </body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but even in this example, Chrome interprets my clicks as actual mouse clicks and not as touches.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that is working for me is to toggle Emulate Touch Events found in Emulation > Sensors in Chrome 45 each time the page is reloaded. This is a pretty crappy solution. Hope someone finds a less annoying fix.

[image]